# How to properly export globals in Python modules?

Tags: python, module, directory, global

I'm seeing this strange behavior with a module, which *only* happens if the module is implemented using an `__init__.py` and another file, containing the 'guts' of the module. So, let's say, I have a module, called `module`, implemented in the `module` directory. This directory contains two files:

1. `__init__.py`

```
# contents of module/__init__.py
from .guts import *
```

2. There's also `guts.py` in the same directory:

```
# contents of module/guts.py
test_x = 1

def inc_x():
    global test_x
    test_x += 1

def print_x(prefix):
    print(f"{prefix} in module: {test_x}")
```

Now, I'm trying to use this module, including its global `test_x` from an application:

```
x = module.test_x
print(f"before in test  : {module.test_x}")
module.print_x("before")
print("incrementing...")
module.inc_x()
print(f"after  in test  : {module.test_x}")
module.print_x("after ")
assert x==module.test_x-1
print("SUCCESS!!\n")
```

If you executed this code under python (I'm using 3.7.6), you get the following output:

```
before in test  : 1
before in module: 1
incrementing...
after  in test  : 1
after  in module: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
assert x==module.test_x-1
AssertionError
```

I'm completely baffled about this behavior, it's almost as if `test_x` had a split personality: one inside the module, one outside.

NOTE: this doesn't happen, if I copy the contents of `guts.py` into `__init__.py` instead if importing it.

NOTE: this also doesn't happen if the module is implemented as a single file (`module.py`) as opposed to in a directory with two files.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what is going on and - ideally - what to do about this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things have happened:

- when you import `*` from `guts`, `test_x` is imported into namespace of `module` and has value `1`.
- when you run `inc_x` you declare `test_x` global, that is global within its module (`guts`).

Now since `int` is immutable (and does not / cannot support in place incrementing), it ultimately / effectively ends up assigning `2` (incremented value) to `test_x` that is global to `guts`.

You can try these two things which may demonstrate that, replace:

```
print(f"after  in test  : {module.test_x}")
```

with:

```
import module.guts
print(f"after  in test  : {module.guts.test_x}")
```

After the same operation, `module.test_x` was 1, but `module.guts.test_x` shows the incremented value as you have expected.

You can also change `guts` to look like this:

```
test_x = [1]

def inc_x():
    global test_x
    test_x[0] += 1

def print_x(prefix):
    print(f"{prefix} in module: {test_x[0]}")
```

And test to match:

```
x = module.test_x[0]
print(f"before in test  : {module.test_x[0]}")
module.print_x("before")
print("incrementing...")
module.inc_x()
print(f"after  in test  : {module.test_x[0]}")
module.print_x("after ")
assert x==module.test_x[0]-1
print("SUCCESS!!\n")
```

Now when you import `guts` you have `module.test_x` being a list (and the very same one as `module.guts.test_x`). When you manipulate items in that list, you are still accessing the same instance, regardless whether it's through `guts.test_x` (also as its global inside `inc_x`) or through `module.test_x`. -> You do not assign new value to `guts.test_x`; you change the object which also `module.test_x` refers to.

That said, I am generally somewhat dubious about `global` and properly. And yeah, they are a good way to confuse anyone reading the code.

---

Regarding your further inquiry: each object has its identity (and resides somewhere in memory). Variables (names) are references to these objects. Assigning to a variable establishes reference to this object:

```
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> a = C()  # create new instance and assign it to a
>>> b = a    # assign that instance to b
>>> c = C()  # create new instance and assign it to c
>>> id(a) == id(b)   # or: a is b
True
>>> id(a) == id(c)   # or: a is c
False
```

Both `a` and `b` are different names referring to the one ans same object.

```
>>> a.a = 1
>>> print(b.a)
1
```

However:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> id(a) == id(b)   # or: a is b
True 
>>> b = 2
>>> id(a) == id(b)   # or: a is b
False
>>> a
1
```

What has happened here? I have an object (literal `int` of value `1`) that I have assigned a name (of variable) `a` and then I have also made `b` reference this same object. However, with `b = 2`, I have not change value of the object, but reassign what `b` refers to (literal `int` with value `2`).

In the first example changing attribute `a` of instance of `class C`. I was modifying the object in place... both keep pointing to the same object (instance). In this second example. I have changed (reassigned) the reference and `a` and `b` no longer point to the same object.

In your function, you have used `+=` operator, that would attempt an in-place addition, but this operation is not (and cannot be) supported by `int` (since it's an immutable type: it cannot be changed in place). I.e. a new object is created and the name is reassign to refer to the result (in this case `a += 1` has the same effect as `a = a + 1`).

Now, even when your variable (name) is `global`, it's still only global within its module. You can inspect global variables using [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), two small files, `m1.py`

```
script_a = 1
# prune keys starting with "__" from printed dict
print("in m1:", {k: v for (k, v) in globals().items() if not k.startswith("__")})
```

and `script.py`:

```
import m1
m1_a = 1
print("in script:", {k: v for (k, v) in globals().items() if not k.startswith("__")})
```

Will give you:

```
$ python3 script.py 
in m1: {'script_a': 1}
in script: {'m1': <module 'm1' from '/tmp/m1.py'>, 'm1_a': 1}
```

This mean when a name is created as a result of `from ... *` import, a new name is created. While initially both name refer to the same object, when you call `inc_x` of `guts` gets reassigned and refers to something new (result of addition) while the other name in `module` still points to the original object (`1`).

Now as hinted. I would generally discourage use of `global` variables as they may result in less obvious behavior and can make future reading and maintenance of the script more difficult. That said, while possible to get the behavior you've wanted by using a type (such as `list`) and modifying the object in place. Crossing module boundaries takes this to another level of making it confusing. It really can be fairly difficult to immediately see effect of change in one part of the code and (possibly unforeseen) effects it may have elsewhere (where import from the same module is also being imported and used in a larger script).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however there are still a few follow-ups:

1. Why is there two `test_x` variables? It appears that importing it from `guts` creates a new variable of the same name that happens to reference the same value that the one in `guts` does. I'm not sure if that's what is really happening but it sure doesn't match my intuition about 'importing' things.

2. Is it true then that there really is no good way of exporting globals from modules implemented in multiple files? Or should I say, the only thing that can reasonably exported are things than don't change (their reference)?